# Why do some developer use 'http' and 'express' to create the server?

Tags: node.js, express

Particularly on this line of code:

I'm kinda new on node.js and most of the tutorials that I've seen initialize the server by

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

app = express();

//omit

http.createServer(app).listen(1337)
```

wherein, if you're already using `express` then you can just do :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// omit

app.listen(1337,function(){

});
```

Are there any major difference between those two code structures?

Comment: You don't even have to look at the code, as one answer suggests. You just have to read the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html), which says "Binds and listens for connections on the specified host and port. This method is **identical** to Node’s `http.Server.listen()`."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No meaningful difference.  In fact, if you look at the code for `app.listen()`, all it does is do `http.createServer()` and than call `.listen()` on it.  It's just meant to be a shortcut that saves you using the `http` module directly.

Here's the [code for `app.listen()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615):

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

Your second code block is just a bit less code because it uses the `app.listen()` shortcut.  Both do the same.

Comment: This is a dup you can close if you have the node badget.